# How to update Django file from local machine to Ubuntu development server(AWS EC2)?

Tags: django, git, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am developing an app in my local machine(**windows OS**) and I am using an **AWS Ubuntu Server** to show updated website to the client in another country. But my problem is that when i am uploading python file through **FileZilla** Sftp, its not make any change on the server till I reboot ubuntu server using "**sudo reboot**"

I am tired of doing this process again and again. I read about **git version control** can help me with this situation but I don't know how to do it.

Please help me I am stuck from 3 days on this.

Comment: Your question is not about uploading files. You are doing that fine. You need to restart the web server process, not the whole machine; what you do entirely depends on how you are serving your site. Note you need to do this *however* you upload your file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reboot all the time. What you should do is simply check the running service or process using "ps -ef | grep processName" and kill it(kill -9 'processId') and restart the process again.